# How to switch between python2 and python3 pip on Fedora 22?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, fedora, python-3.4

As I have started to use Python 3.4, I need pip to maintain libraries on both Python 2.7 and Python 3.4.

How to select the appropriate pip quickly using terminal?

Note:
This question is **NOT** related to Virtualenv but with the default python2.7 and python3.4 that comes with Fedora 22 Workstation.

As a temporary fix, I am using PyCharm to manage libraries.

Comment: Don't you have `pip` for 2.7 and `pip3` for 3.4?

Comment: I get same results when I use pip and pip3. [root@localhost ~]# pip -V
`pip 7.1.0 from /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages (python 3.4)`
[root@localhost ~]# pip3 -V
`pip 7.1.0 from /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages (python 3.4)`

Comment: Have you tried e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/2812520/3001761?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fedora separates Python 2.x and 3.x's environments. `yum install python-pip` will give you an executable called `pip` which you can use for Python 2.x packages, and `yum install python3-pip` will give you an executable called `pip3`for managing Python 3.x packages.

You can install either, both or neither - they will not interfere with each other.

Answer (score 4):

I never use `pip install` directly (when outside a venv, at least).

Instead I use `python-<version> -m pip install --user <packages>`, which always does what I really meant regardless of what version the wrapper scripts are for. This is especially useful if I've locally installed a newer version of pip.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Fedora 23 and I have the package `python3-pip` already installed but there's no `pip3` nor `python3-pip` command in my path, so the way I've found to use `pip3` is to invoke it through `python3` executable:

```
python3 -mpip
```

For example, to install `mps-youtube`:

```
sudo python3 -mpip install mps-youtube
```

Answer (score 0):

on fedora 25 you can just do the following:

- copy file `sudo cp /usr/bin/pip /usr/bin/pip3`
- then edit it to change `#!/usr/bin/python` to `#!/usr/bin/python3`
- do `pip3 -V` to see that works.

this solution can also work on others version of fedora.